# MySQL : query question

Tags: mysql

[image]

There are one-one relationship between room and application means an application must occupy a room. If I want to get the room that doesn't occupied by application, how to write sql to query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from room r
where not exists (select 1 
                 from application a
                 where a.roomId = r.roomId)
```

OR

```
select * 
from room r left outer join
     application a on r.roomId = a.roomId
where a.roomId is null
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT roomID,description  FROM  room WHERE roomID NOT IN ( SELECT roomID from application )
```

Comment: avoid not in.. use not exists instead.. generally far better in terms of performance

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:

- Look at all the existing rooms
- Look at all the rooms used by existing applications
- The difference between those is the rooms which are not used by any of the applications

  `select roomID from room where roomID not in (select roomID from application)`

should do the trick.